# How to block the user after a few failed logins

Tags: users, security

modules like [login security](https://drupal.org/project/login_security) deny the user IP after afew failed logins. there are softwares that randomly generate new IP for user so it makes such modules useless. sending cookie to the user browser is also unreliable because the user can disable accepting cookie. What is the most reliable solution to block some users?

Answer (score 0):

[Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) is what comes to mind. You can react to the user logging in I guess.